# Rewriting path for a specific file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a friendly url for a specific file from a directory that has a long file path as well as renaming the file. I am not even sure if this is possible.

So far I have tried in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule eventdays-2012/brochure.pdf(.+)$ sites/default/files/docs/fact_sheet-204499207.pdf
```

... but this is not working.

I've done some searching and see where you can mask an entire directory in the file path but in my case I just want to do one file within the directory, create a directory name and change the file name as well.

Comment: How would you normally access `fact_sheet-204499207.pdf`? You can't access files outside of your document root without an Alias.

Comment: @JonLin - /sites/default/files/ etc.. is under the document root already and i just want a psuedo directory under the doc root to be "eventdays-2012". I probably should not have used the word "virtual"

Comment: Where is the document root? `/sites/default`?

Comment: root is `example.com` where `example.com/sites` is a sub-directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `(.+)` part from your regular expression. It makes it so you *need* something after the `brochure.pdf`. Also add some boundaries:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/?eventdays-2012/brochure.pdf$ /sites/default/files/docs/fact_sheet-204499207.pdf [L]
```