# htacces rewrite single file

Tags: .htaccess, file, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a specific file on my website to another one by using htaccess:

```
# General
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Rewrite file
RewriteRule ^/file.html$ /dir/file.html [L]
```

This is the .htaccess code i'm using based on snippets i found on the internet.
Somehow this is not working, the server is returning a 404-Not-found error.

I can't see any difference with example's that are said to work, like in
[Rewriting path for a specific file using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699847/rewriting-path-for-a-specific-file-using-htaccess)

**Edit:**
If I place file.html in the root-folder, I can view it. So the rewrite definitely is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule does not receive leading slash. Write so:

```
RewriteRule ^file.html$ /dir/file.html [L]
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem (together with the fact that i didn't know the file will be executed several times until no rewrites are done anymore).