# HTML : file-download: controle favicon and Tab-Title

Tags: javascript, html, browser, download

My file download works great. The file is delivered correctly. But I want to make it prettier.

Is there a way to set a favicon and a window title, if I click on a html-download link to a file in a new tab?

the file is generated and streamed by php.

client part:

```
<a target="_blank" tabindex="0" href="/path/to/file-download/interface" >
```

server stream, while `$file` is some array holding file information:

```
    if (file_exists($file['path'])) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
        $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file['path']);

        if( strstr($mime, "image") !== false ){
            header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
            header('Content-Disposition: filename='.basename($file['path']));
        } else {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file['path']));
        }

        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file['path']));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file['path']);
        exit;
    } else {
        error_log("File for download >".$file['path']."< not found.");
        return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
An additional problem is, that there is a favicon already in the root folder, but I want to show a different one.

Comment: You could do as many sites do nowadays, which is to send the user to a page that says "Your download will begin shortly" (or a blank page), and on this page, trigger a redirect to your download. This way, while you are waiting for the download to complete, you'll be showing this page (whether it's blank or not) with your favicon.

Comment: Thanx @blex for the comment - sounds like a hack. is there no way to add headers which do this, or any other native way?

Comment: Indeed, that might be a bit overkill for just a favicon. I'm not aware of any header you can set for this. However, I believe browsers will automatically try to fetch a `favicon.ico` file at the root of your domain. Is it located there? If not, you could try to put one there. And if you don't want to put it there, have a look at [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958770/1913729). If that does not work, I'm afraid I can't help you any further

Comment: @blex I am afraid that is part of the problem - see update. anyway, thanks for your try.