# How to set table title in HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring

We are showing file in a broser using

```
shiowMethod(final String viewType, final String filename,HttpServletResponse response){
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(docasnyObsah.getSoubor().length));
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "private");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", ContentDisposition.create(zobrazeni , "my_file.pdf", 
       "My title"));
        response.flushBuffer();
}

public static String create(final String viewType, final String filename, final String fieldName) {
    try {
        final String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).replace("+", "%20");
        if(fieldName.isEmpty()){
            return String.format("%1$s; filename*=UTF-8''%2$s; filename=\"%2$s\"", viewType, encoded);
        }
        else {
            String test = String.format("%1$s; filename*=UTF-8''%2$s; name=\"%3$s\"; filename=\"%2$s\"", viewType, encoded, fieldName);
            return test;
        }


    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new ShouldNotHappenRuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I would expect this will set title of tab to be "My title" but instead of this the viewType is shown like this

[image]

the values sent to submetod are

```
viewType = "inline"
filename = "my_file.pdf"
fieldName = "My title"
```

What I need to change to be able to set html page tab name?

Comment: Simmilar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002043/html-file-download-controle-favicon-and-tab-title

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition